# How to save file to local hdd using asp or other script running naturally on IIS

Tags: php, javascript, asp.net, dojo

I am writing Dojo web application that has a dojo enhanced datagrid. After the datagid is populated with data, i have option that saves the file to the user's machine. To do this i am using Dojo csv [exporter](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojox/grid/EnhancedGrid/plugins/Exporter.html) that creates a string from the datagrid in CSV format. In the following code i am passing that string to a csv.php script that allows me to save the string as csv file.

The code using the dojo exporter:

```
var g = dijit.byId("grid");
g.exportGrid("csv", {
    writerArgs: {
        separator: ","
    }
}, function(str){
       debugger;
     //the code below is used if the user prefers to have call to the php script on a php enabled server
     var form = document.createElement('form');
     dojo.attr(form, 'method', 'POST');
     document.body.appendChild(form);
     dojo.io.iframe.send({
     url: "csv.php",
     form: form,
     method: "POST",
     content: {exp: str},
     timeout: 15000
     });

     document.body.removeChild(form);
});
```

The php code for csv.php:

```
<?
$time = time();
header("Pragma: public");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-type: application/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"grid_$time.csv\"");
$exportedData = $_POST['exp'];
echo stripslashes($exportedData);
exit;
?>
```

So the problem i have is that i am using php and that requires using php enabled server. If the person deploying the application has such a server, no problem the code works. however, if he uses IIS installation of php and specific settings  in IIS are needed. 
I want to write code that can be run on IIs without extra set up. I was thinking tht ASP is the way to go, but i am open to any suggestions and help. How can i rewrite that csv.php code in asp.

Thanks

If something is wrong with my question please do not remove it, but let me know what to change.

Update:

This is the code i have in the ashx page, but now i get the "500 Internal Server Error". I have the asp.net installed on IIS, so it it is not the problem. In the js file i only changed scv.php to csv.ashx. Do i have to use different code to call the ashx?

```
   <%

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;

namespace WebApplication2
{

    public class Handler1 : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
         context.Request.Files(0);
            Dim reader = new IO.StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream);
            Dim string = reader.ReadToEnd();
            context.Response.ContentType = "application/csv";
            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Whatever.csv");
            context.Response.AddHeader("content-length", context.Request.ContentLength.ToString());

            Response.Write("something");
            if( context.Response.IsClientConnected )
                context.Response.Flush();
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
%>
```

Comment: Can you explain "specific settings in IIS are needed"? I have deployed a few PHP applications on IIS and they all worked fine. I you consider to migrate to ASP, please choose ASP.NET, which is the successor of ASP.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have to support both. The idea is to avoid extra confusion and extra deployment time for people that will deploy the app. I have a Json conig file that is the only thing that will be changed when deploying the app. In that file the IT person will specify the server they are using.

Comment: You still did not reply to my question. What are the specific settings that are needed in order to run your application. The answer strongly depends on these settings...

Comment: The regular setting to use PHP on IIS: http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis7.php

Comment: You won't get around these settings, they are required in order to run PHP on IIS. But there is an easier way to do this: Use the Microsoft Web Platform Installer and choose one of the PHP packages.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use .Net 4.5 and just create a simple web app. I don't like php.

[C# .Net 4.5 version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfezx97z.aspx)

[Classic ASP version](https://web.archive.org/web/20210513000801/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/faq/FileSystemObject/faq3.shtml)

That should give you a pretty good idea of how to do the same thing. For speed of development reasons it may be more worth it to you to write it in classic ASP... Although, that is much more dated.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help on the php side of things but for asp.net you could write a Generic Handler .ashx page.  Have your existing page post to that and from within there you can manipulate the response much like your php example.

```
context.Response.ContentType = "application/csv"
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Whatever.csv")
context.Response.AddHeader ("content-length", YourPostedData.Length)
context.Response.Write(YourPostedData)
If context.Response.IsClientConnected Then
    context.Response.Flush()
End If
```

Comment: I have created the ashx page, i have dropped the file in my app directory in ISS and now i am getting the "500 Internal Server Error". I have asp.net installed on my IIS. Any ideas? I have added the code to my question...

Comment: You need to add a bit more code to read in the data that was posted to the ashx and then write it out via the line you removed  context.Response.Write(YourPostedData)

Comment: Dim reader As New IO.StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream)
    Dim csvdata As String = reader.ReadToEnd() I think will read in the data how you are posting it

Comment: I did edit the code, but seems that the problem is in the way i POST to IIS. I get this "500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost/...(the pat to the file).../csv.ashx"

Comment: Try changing the 
content: {exp: str},
to
data: str,

Comment: same problem, however i discovered in fiddler that the response from the server is the actual file, not its content?!

Comment: Oh if it is sending as an actual file you can try context.Request.Files(0)

Comment: I did update the code, but id does not seems to change anything. See above. Also, i see more detailed error in firebug :"The page must have a <%@ webhandler class="MyNamespace.MyClass" ... %> directive." Thanks for helping!

Comment: Ah I have never made one with out using a code behind.  SO do you have it all working now?

Comment: No, i am codding some different way to call the ashx, with the webhandler ... more problems occurred....